# Movie: Man discovers he is one of many clones

Tags: story-identification, movie, clones

I remember a movie about clones from when I was a kid. I think it was on TV, so it may have been a made for TV movie.

The plot, as I remember it, concerned a man who finds out he is a clone, then finds out he is one of many clones.  There was a big secret lab with lots of clones of him growing, and the final scene was of several of the clones going off to find their own lives in the world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [*The Clone Master*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077345/)

> In order to test the validity of his experiments on cloning, a scientist makes clones of himself, but it causes problems that he didn't foresee.

Answer (score 6):

I think [*The Clonus Horror*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078062/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

> Politicians scheme to clone themselves, assuring immortal life.
>
> Parts: The Clonus Horror, also known as Clonus, is a 1979 science fiction horror film about an isolated community in a remote desert area, where clones are bred to serve as a source of replacement organs for the wealthy and powerful. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts:_The_Clonus_Horror)

I am fairly certain I watched this movie on MST3K. At the end

> the main character and a few others escape the clone prison to try and live their own lives.

This movie was then sort of unofficially remade with the 2005 movie [*The Island*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_%282005_film%29). Which resulted in a lawsuit that DreamWorks settled out of court.

Comment: I've looked at The Clonus Horror, and I don't think that's the one I remember.  Reviewing the MST3K version that's on Youtube, looks like the ending (spoiler alert) scene is at a political convention with a confrontation of Peter Graves' character.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [*The 6th Day*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0216216/) with Arnold Schwarzenegger?

> Futuristic action about a man who meets a clone of himself and stumbles into a grand conspiracy about clones taking over the world.

Comment: The tags and the question's earlier title indicate the movie is from the 70s.  *The 6th Day* is from 2000.

Comment: This is what I would suggest too ;-) But it seems Bob did find his movie 2 hrs ago. The Arnold version had them check their eyelids for dots to see which 'version' there are if I'm not mistaken. Once they do that, they find out they are one of many and get mad/sad, mayhem happens, and then they go their own way.

Comment: While a bit late to the party given the original querent has stated they found the answer, I appreciate the thought, and having incorrect answers that nonetheless fit the criteria help when someone has a similar question with a different answer, so you get a vote up from me.

Answer (score 0):

Tossing this one into the mix just because it too fits (most) of the criteria.
[*Natural Selection*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109547/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_181) (*Dark Reflection*) a 1994 TV movie.

> Software programmer Ben Braden has it all: beautiful wife, cute kid, dream house, sports car, great job. Then one day the doorbell rings and he finds himself standing eye to eye with Alex Connelly, every inch his double and hell-bent on getting Ben's material features as well...

Comment: Could you edit to explain how this matches?

Comment: Especially the "many clones" aspect. At this point, this sounds closer to Stephen King's *The Dark Half* than to the OP's request.